# DPDK sample application aborts after EAL: Couldn't get fd on hugepage file

Tags: dpdk, huge-pages

After cloning the [dpdk git repository](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk) and building the *helloworld* application, I get the following error:

```
$ ./examples/helloworld/build/helloworld
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /run/user/1000/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Couldn't get fd on hugepage file
EAL: error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
EAL: rte_service_init() failed
PANIC in main():
Cannot init EAL
5: [./examples/helloworld/build/helloworld(+0x11de) [0x56175faac1de]]
4: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f31f60fe0b3]]
3: [./examples/helloworld/build/helloworld(+0x111c) [0x56175faac11c]]
2: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.so.20.0(__rte_panic+0xc5) [0x7f31f62d537e]]
1: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.so.20.0(rte_dump_stack+0x32) [0x7f31f62ecc52]]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Checked hugepage support and it seems fine:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i huge
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:     256
HugePages_Free:      255
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:          524288 kB

$ mount | grep huge
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)

$ cat /proc/filesystems | grep huge
nodev   hugetlbfs

$ cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
256
```

I saw a workaround in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772125/dpdk-hello-world-error-allocating-rte-services-array-in-custom-linux); run it with the `--no-huge` option, which works:

```
$ ./examples/helloworld/build/helloworld --no-huge
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Static memory layout is selected, amount of reserved memory can be adjusted with -m or --socket-mem
EAL: Multi-process socket /run/user/1000/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:01.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
hello from core 1
hello from core 2
hello from core 3
hello from core 0
```

But this is a limiting solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR Use `sudo`**

Running with `--log-level=eal,8` as suggested by @VipinVarghese revealed that this was a permissions issue:

```
$ ./examples/helloworld/build/helloworld --log-level=eal,8
EAL: Detected lcore 0 as core 0 on socket 0
EAL: Detected lcore 1 as core 0 on socket 0
EAL: Detected lcore 2 as core 0 on socket 0
EAL: Detected lcore 3 as core 0 on socket 0
EAL: Support maximum 128 logical core(s) by configuration.
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: open shared lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk/pmds-20.0/librte_pmd_qede.so
EAL: Registered [vdev] bus.
EAL: Registered [pci] bus.
EAL: Registered [eth] device class.
EAL: open shared lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk/pmds-20.0/librte_pmd_aesni_mb.so
...
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x61000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0xd00600000 (size = 0x61000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x800kB at socket 0
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x400000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0xd00800000 (size = 0x400000000)
EAL: TSC frequency is ~2590000 KHz
EAL: Master lcore 0 is ready (tid=7fc11ed01d00;cpuset=[0])
EAL: lcore 2 is ready (tid=7fc116ffd700;cpuset=[2])
EAL: lcore 3 is ready (tid=7fc1167fc700;cpuset=[3])
EAL: lcore 1 is ready (tid=7fc1177fe700;cpuset=[1])
EAL: Trying to obtain current memory policy.
EAL: Setting policy MPOL_PREFERRED for socket 0
EAL: get_seg_fd(): open failed: Permission denied
EAL: Couldn't get fd on hugepage file
EAL: attempted to allocate 1 segments, but only 0 were allocated
EAL: Restoring previous memory policy: 0
EAL: error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
EAL: rte_service_init() failed
PANIC in main():
Cannot init EAL
5: [./examples/helloworld/build/helloworld(+0x11de) [0x56459e5391de]]
4: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7fc11eed00b3]]
3: [./examples/helloworld/build/helloworld(+0x111c) [0x56459e53911c]]
2: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.so.20.0(__rte_panic+0xc5) [0x7fc11f0a737e]]
1: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.so.20.0(rte_dump_stack+0x32) [0x7fc11f0bec52]]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Tried solving the permissions problem (*EAL: get_seg_fd(): open failed: Permission denied*), but it only worked when I ran it as root:

```
$ sudo ./examples/helloworld/build/helloworld
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:01.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
hello from core 1
hello from core 2
hello from core 3
hello from core 0
```

As it turns out, this is the correct approach, even though the [documentation](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/build_sample_apps.html) appears to assume that this is obvious. There is no mention of root privileges required on section *"6.2. Running a Sample Application"*, excerpt below:

> Copy the DPDK application binary to your target, then run the
> application as follows (assuming the platform has four memory channels
> per processor socket, and that cores 0-3 are present and are to be
> used for running the application):
>
> ./dpdk-helloworld -l 0-3 -n 4

However, this point is mentioned later in the documentation, see "[8.2. Running DPDK Applications Without Root Privileges](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/enable_func.html)" where there's a clear note:

> The instructions below will allow running DPDK as non-root with older
> Linux kernel versions. However, since version 4.0, the kernel does not
> allow unprivileged processes to read the physical address information
> from the pagemaps file, making it impossible for those processes to
> use HW devices which require physical addresses

There is also a hint in the [FAQ](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-2.1/faq/faq.html):

> 1. What does “EAL: map_all_hugepages(): open failed: Permission denied Cannot init memory” mean? This is most likely due to the test
>    application not being run with sudo to promote the user to a
>    superuser. Alternatively, applications can also be run as regular
>    user. For more information, please refer to DPDK Getting Started
>    Guide.

And an [email](https://mails.dpdk.org/archives/users/2016-July/000709.html) touching on this topic:

```
2016-07-07 16:47, Jez Higgins:
> Is it possible to get DPDK up and running as non-root - if so, can
> anyone guide me to what I'm missing? Or should I be giving this up as a
> bad job?

You can try the --no-huge option.
But most of drivers won't work without hugepage currently.
A rework of the memory allocation is needed to make it work better.
```

That was four years ago. Perhaps there is already a solution which does not require `sudo` or `--no-huge`? If so, other answers are most welcome. For now, I'm going with this.

Comment: this_still_works. Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

@Nagev I request you to check [dpdk as non root stack overflow question in Nov 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664141/running-dpdk-without-root-permisions/64666019#64666019)

[EDIT-1] Noticed the above question is removed, hence access to the details are limited, updating with the answer [how to run without sudo or root privellege section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571932/can-you-run-dpdk-in-a-non-privileged-container-as-as-non-root-user/69178969#comment122283933_69178969)

Note: I have been running DPDK application as non root with 18.11.5 LTS and 19.11.3 LTS

Comment: Thanks. The content no longer exists at the link you posted.

Comment: I can acees the link and post the answer back, but it looks like you already have posted the answer based on the comments shared. So do you still need the content?

Comment: I don't need it.